# jquery autocomplete not displaying the values of array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

hi i am using jquery autocomplete with codeigniter my reslut array is coming from database and i am sending back the array using json_encode(). but in response i am not able to show the values in the search but i get the empty reslut, means i get values but i am not able to display but values are coming i can see the empty lis, my data array is like this

```
[{"countryid":"1","countryname":"Afghanistan"},{"countryid":"2","countryname":"Albania"},{"countryid":"3","countryname":"Algeria"},{"countryid":"4","countryname":"American Samoa"},{"countryid":"5","countryname":"Andorra"}]
```

my model function is like this

```
public function search_countries($string)
    {
        $this->db->like('countryname', $string);
        $query = $this->db->get('countries');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

my controller function is this

```
public function search_countries()
    {
        $string = $this->input->post('countryname');
        $data = $this->user_m->search_countries($string);
        $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

and here is jquery function

```
$( ".country" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.post("signup/search_countries", {countryname: request.term}, function(data){
            response(data, function( data ) {
              return {
                label: data.countryid,
                value: data.countryname
              }
            });
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: You need to use correct keys as in returning json.

Comment: keys are correct @cubuzoa

Comment: And also have you checked your response data on firebug? Is it correct and you are not getting any js error right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only giving js part;

```
$( ".country" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.post("signup/search_countries", {countryname: request.term}, function(data){
            response($.map( data, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.countryname,
                value: item.countryid
              }
            }));
        });
      }
    });
```

Coudl you please try this?

Comment: thanks but its not working. it shows the result but in empty lists. i can hover also but these are blank elements

Comment: Could you please check your response json keys?

Comment: Ok, I updated code. Could you please try again. I forgot to use map

Comment: thanks @cubuzoa it worked but there are some errors i corrected. and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be:

```
            label: data.countryid,
            value: data.countryName
```

as :

```
            label: data.countryid,
            value: data.countryname
```

going by your actual json response that you are receiving (change `Name` to `name` in `countryName`).

Comment: @ahmadgulzar then you should correct that in the above question, as it still shows contryName, whereas your json response shows countryname.

Comment: @ahmadgulzar are you using firebug? can you check, if you are even receiving any response from the server or not?, also try to do something like `console.log(data)` , so that we can be sure if its just a string or is actually converted to a JS Object.

Comment: yes i am receiving the response. when i get the value in alert() then it shows like this [object object]